# Shopify - Pass a variable into a if statement?

Tags: shopify

I am trying to display a list of products on the customer/account.liquid page based on a tag a customer has.

At the very top of my file I have captured my variable called topic

```
{% capture topic %}
{% for tag in customer.tags %}
{{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
```

Then a couple lines later I want to re-use my variable in a if statement to show only the products with the exact same tag.

I have done this at the moment but I can't get it to work.

```
   {% for product in collections.all.products %}
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
    {% if tag contains [topic] %}
    <a href="{{ product.url }}">
      {% for image in product.images %}
      <img src="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}">
      {% endfor %}
      <span>{{ product.title }}</span>
      <span>{{ product.type }}</span>
    </a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Can you help me spot my mistake ?

Thanks a lot !

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your approach. The Customer Tags is an array and the value of topic would be all the tags as string after your for loop. Because of that your comparison fails with a single tag. The below code should work fine for you.

```
{% for product in collections.all.products %}
    {% assign displayProduct = false %}
    
    {% for tag in product.tags %}
        {% if customer.tags contains tag %}
            {% assign displayProduct = true%}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

  {% if displayProduct == true %}
    <a href="{{ product.url }}">
      
      {% for image in product.images %}
        <img src="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'medium' }}">
      {% endfor %}
      
      <span>{{ product.title }}</span>
      <span>{{ product.type }}</span>

    </a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In the above code, you iterate over each product tag and see of the customer tags array contain the same value. If so, set the displayProduct to true. The reason to use flag variable instead of just using the if condition to display product is, this prevents rendering same product multiple times if the user and product has multiple same tags.

You can improve this further by iterating over products only if customer has some tags.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bilal. That works as intended and I really appreciate the details in your explanation. 
One final ask if I may. I forgot to mention that I'd like to display ALL products if the customer doesn't have a tag and I am confused to how I should adapt this model.

Thanks again !

Comment: You can use *size* to get array size of customer tags and then use if else condition to render all products or only product with tags. Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course ! That makes total sense. 
I went with  {% assign nbtags = customer.tags | size %} and then {% if nbtags == 0 %} and it worked perfectly. Thank you again for your help !